# How to make viewViewAppear getting called in both Master and Detail view whenever they appear

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, viewwillappear

My app has 5 screens which are controlled by a tabbar at bottom, and one of them is a SplitView.

My Problem is:

- The master view is just cause viewWillAppear only one time at first rotation.
- The detail view is also just cause viewWillAppear only one time at first load.

While I would like viewViewAppear of both master and detail view are getting called each time this screen is opened, because there are 5 different screens, and user may leave this screen to view another, so I would like to know whenever master and details view appear to change layout or refresh data.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think cause is UISplitViewController is a single root view model, so viewWillAppear is just called one time, is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just anwsered your own question. I know its something you dont want to hear but apple's documentation says it must get the root view. Try to restructure your app a bit.

Link to documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW2

From the documentation:

> A split view controller must always be
>   the root of any interface you create.
>   In other words, you must always
>   install the view from
>   aUISplitViewController object as the
>   root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split-view
>   interface may then contain navigation
>   controllers, tab bar controllers, or
>   any other type of view controller you
>   need to implement your interface.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried an easier way and not effect to existing screens that I use 2 tableView to simulate splitView and it is working well.

Comment: That seems like the best choice -- using the standard UISplitViewController will only cause frustrations. A custom class is needed. I found a custom SplitViewController that does something very similar to what you want. Its definitely worth checking out [link](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController/) by a Slatvick. --- and another one from CocoaIsMyGirlfriend [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/) --- lastly, the one from Matt Gemmel [link](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad)

Comment: Non-Embedded Links:
Slatvick
https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController/
CocoaIsMyGirlfriend
http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/
Matt Gemmel
http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad